# Problemas para importar excel a base de datos PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php

Buen dia, estoy intentado importar un documento .csv que contiene 4 columnas las cuales son nombre, turno, fecha_inicial, fecha _final, el problema que tengo es que cuando importo el archivo la informacion de nombre y turno si me aparece en la base de datos pero las fechas se guardan como 0000-00-00, ya revise del lado de excel y la fecha tiene el formato correcto, me podrian orientar que parte estoy omitiendo o cual es el error por el cual la fecha no se guarda correctamente?

Comment: Has revisado la estructura del date en phpmyadmin? por norma general tiene la estructura inglesa YYYY-MM-DD, por lo que quizá tengas que hacer en php un dateformat para que excel te lo reconozca bien

Comment: quizá entendí mal tu pregunta, no necesitas importar un csv a una base de datos phpmyadmin?

Comment: Si eso estoy tratando, importar con php un csv a phpmyadmin

Comment: @Xavi Tal y como está redactada la pregunta, es algo general y no podemos saber qué es lo que está fallando en concreto. Por favor, incluye un ejemplo de los datos que hay en el csv y también el código PHP y la estructura de tu tabla en la base de datos, también el log de errores (si los hay). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: No conozco la base de datos Phpmyadmin, ¿cuál es esa?

Answer (score 0):

Edita tu archivo de excel, mysql requiere el formato 'YYYY-MM-DD' para un DATE y el formato 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss' para DATETIME.